# Axios Request Error: Unrecognized event: {"type":"client_log","level":"log","data":["[Error: Network Error]"]}

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, axios

I've been working on a MERN stack project for some time (React Native Frontend + Nodejs Backend), and suddenly my axios requests stop working (I'd been making axios calls on this exact same project for weeks now, but suddenly it started throwing this Network Error). I try to make a simple get request, but this is the error I get:

```
Unrecognized event: {"type":"client_log","level":"log","data":["[Error: Network Error]"]}

Network Error
- node_modules\axios\lib\core\createError.js:15:17 in createError
- node_modules\axios\lib\adapters\xhr.js:80:22 in handleError
- node_modules\event-target-shim\dist\event-target-shim.js:818:20 in EventTarget.prototype.dispatchEvent
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Network\XMLHttpRequest.js:575:10 in setReadyState
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Network\XMLHttpRequest.js:389:6 in __didCompleteResponse
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\vendor\emitter\EventEmitter.js:189:10 in emit
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:425:19 in __callFunction
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:112:6 in __guard$argument_0
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:373:10 in __guard
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:111:4 in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
* [native code]:null in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
```

I know this is not a problem with my backend, because I can make API calls via Postman just fine. But when I try calling the API from my frontend using axios.get().... I keep getting this same error. I have no idea why all of a sudden axios decided to stop working on me, but I am pretty sure axios is my problem here..

Here is my axios call:

```
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:5000/post/viewPosts")
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data);
        this.setState({
          redMarkers: res.data,
        });
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

Anyone have any suggestions for how to fix this?? Thanks. (I'm also 99% sure I have no problem with my CORS since I've double and triple checked that I included the app.use(cors())).

Comment: It's not able to load the URL you provided. Can you get a result from `curl http://localhost:5000/post/viewPosts` using on the command line?

Comment: i think i realized what i did wrong.... this is a react native projects so the axios needs to be requesting to my computers IP ADDRESS NOT LOCALHOST... i hate myslef

Answer (score 0):

You should try to change `localhost` by your local IP.